# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: breeze.generic.UFunc$UImpl2 when using Breeze DenseVector

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

Using Breeze I get a runtime error:
Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: breeze.generic.UFunc $ UImpl2.

I can not understand what I'm wrong about, and unfortunately my online searches did not help me. Here is the code:

```
import breeze.linalg.DenseVector
object Sample {
  def main(args : Array[String]) {
    val w = DenseVector(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0)
    val x = DenseVector(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0)
    val y: Double = w dot x
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely either missing a dependency when running your program, or mixing versions of breeze. It is hard to tell from the amount of information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
Inserting these rows into POM.xml I created a jar with all the missing dependencies:

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It works.